# how i can acess to elements of arraylist<class>

Tags: java, class, arraylist

hi i want to know how i can access to elements of arraylist in java?
i have this class .

```
class flight 
{
    public String start;
    public String end;
    public int timethatend ;
    public int timethatstart;
    flight ( int ts , int tf , String s , String e )
    {
        this.start = s;
        this.end =e;
        this.timethatend = tf;
        this.timethatstart = ts;
    }   
}
```

and i have this arraylist in my main class

```
ArrayList<flight>list = new ArrayList<flight>();
```

now i want print the elements of arraylist i use this syntax

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

but the out put is this
`flight@1f96302` 
what should i do?
                                                                           another question how i can change them for example i want change the time of takeoff the first flight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is printing the object reference to your flight object. You need to add a toString() method to your Flight class and use it to print the flight info. For example:

```
public String toString() {
    return start + "," + timethatstart + "," + end + "," + timethatend;
}
```

When you print:

```
System.out.println(list.get(0).toString());
```

Comment: and how i can acess the elements for  change them . for example for flight 1 i want change the time that it takeoff . what should i do?

Comment: You are accessing the element with list.get(index). You can directly change its variables, for example: `list.get(0).timethatstart = 2400`, or use setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Add a toString method in the class like below:

```
class flight
{
    public String start;
    public String end;
    public int timethatend ;
    public int timethatstart;
    flight ( int ts , int tf , String s , String e )
    {
        this.start = s;
        this.end =e;
        this.timethatend = tf;
        this.timethatstart = ts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "flight{" +
                "start='" + start + '\'' +
                ", end='" + end + '\'' +
                ", timethatend=" + timethatend +
                ", timethatstart=" + timethatstart +
                '}';
    }
}
```

To add new flight elements in the arraylist, to the following:

```
flight f = new flight(1,2,"12","34");
ArrayList<flight> list = new ArrayList<flight>();
list.add(f);
```

To change the value of some element, do the following:

```
list.get(0).start = "1234";
```